# How to trim null values on a binary column with fixed length in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, binary

I have the following column definition:

```php
$table->char('encrypted_key', 190)->charset('binary')
```

When I `dump(bin2hex($key))` before storing the data, I get:

```
[...]df6d1261639c76e191
```

However, when I retrieve the data, the empty spaces at the end are filled with null values, note the zeros at the end:

```
[...]df6d1261639c76e191000000000000
```

I would like to keep the size definition of the column for good practice, but I am not sure how to properly trim the null values at the end of the output-data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `trim` function

```
$text = trim($key);
```

Or

```
$text = trim($key, "\x00..\x1F");
```